# Python Turtle: I want to make a function that executes another function depending on what the previously executed function was

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm drawing my name using turtles and I have a bunch of different functions for each of the letters

like so (for letter r)

```
def letter_r(t):

    def letter_r_top(t):
        turtle.lt(90)
        turtle.fd(150)
        turtle.rt(90)
        turtle.circle(-37.5,180)
        turtle.lt(130)

    def letter_r_leg(t):
        csquare = ((75**2) + (37.5**2)) 
        sidec = math.sqrt(csquare)
        turtle.fd(sidec)

    letter_r_top(rob)
    letter_r_leg(rob)
```

After each letter, i need to move the turtle into the right place to setup for the next letter.  Because each of the letters are different sizes I need to make custom movements depending on what the previous letter is but I dont want to make separate functions for each of those movements.

At the end of my code I have the list of functions to be called in the correct order to spell my name

```
 letter_t(rob)
 letter_setup(rob)
 letter_r(rob)
 letter_setup(rob)
 .....
```

Is there a way that I can do something like this so that I will only need 1 setup function.(Not real code, just a conceptualization of what I'm thinking

```
def letter_setup(t):
    if previously executed function A 
        turtle.fd(75)
    if previously executed function B 
        turtle.fd(75)
        turtle.lt(90)
    if previously executed function C
        turtle.fd(75)
        turtle.lt(90)
```

Comment: Include all the setups in the functions themselves. Like if your call `letter_t(rob)` you should then reset the cursor to a predefined location (like lower right corner of `t`). So the next function knows where the cursor is. Every function will now assume the cursor is at the lower *left* of the to-be-drawn letter.

Comment: This problem is way simpler than you are thinking it is.

Comment: I forgot to add this in the original post, but part of the acceptance criterion is that I need to make sure it works/looks right if the letters are completely jumbled/ in a random order.  So I'll need a different movement for an O following an R than an O following an E.

Comment: It will not matter the order of letters if you do it as I said. Think of the letters as blocks. Whatever you draw in the boxes, you start and end at the corners.

Answer (score 1):

Why not the movement to the right place for the next letter at the end of the previous letter?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps there is a better way to do this but you could make a variable last_function_called and in each function you give it a different value then you'll know wich one was the last called :

```
last_function_called = NONE;

def function1():
    last_function_called = FUNCTION1
    blablabla

...

if (last_function_called == FUNCTION1):
    call another one
```

and before of course something like :

```
NONE = 0
FUNCTION1 = 1
FUNCTION2 = 2
ect...
```

Comment: You need `global` in the functions for this to work. Anyway it is a bad way of doing it. It reminds me of some `C` code I wrote and I hate myself for them ;-)